# XMLReader misrepresenting element in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

How do I use XmlReader to read an XML file with the following format? I've been at it for days, but to no avail. When it reaches the `<text>` element, the reader reads it as an end element and ignores the value...No Idea why...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questions>
   <question>
      <question_number>1</question_number>
      <text>DDDDDFFFFJJJJ</text>
      <option>
         <id>1</id>
         <response>DDDF</response>
      </option>
      <option>
         <id>2</id>
         <response>FF</response>
      </option>
      <option>
         <id>3</id>
         <response />
      </option>
      <option>
         <id>4</id>
         <response />
      </option>
   </question>
</questions>
```

I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
public bool ImportQuestions(string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FileName);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "question")
                {
                    Question question = new Question();
                    var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                    while (subReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (subReader.Name == "question_number")
                        {
                            question.Id = subReader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                        }else if (subReader.Name == "text")
                        {
                            question.QuestionText = subReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        } else if (subReader.Name == "option")
                        {
                            Option option = new Option();
                            var ansReader = subReader.ReadSubtree();
                            while (ansReader.Read())
                            {
                                if (ansReader.Name == "id")
                                {
                                    option.ID = ansReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                }else if (ansReader.Name == "response")
                                {
                                    option.Response = ansReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                }
                            }
                            question.AddToAnswers(option);
                        }

                    }
                    Questions.Add(question);
                }

            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use XmlReader? Wouldn't Linq2Xml be a more appropriate fit?

Comment: I grabbed your code and pasted it into LinqPAD, it seems to be working fine (I am able to print out the "text" value without issue and keep going to read the "option" subelements. Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere?

Comment: It picked up some empty text after identifying <question_number> then skips to <question_text> and breaks with this exception "The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type EndElement. Line 1, position 117."

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been at it for days, but to no avail.

Let me make it easier with `LINQ to XML`,Just add two class `Question`, and `Option` like this:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `LINQ to XML`:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("filepath");
var questions = xDoc.Descendants("question").Select(q => new Question
        {
            Number = (int) q.Element("question_number"),
            Text = (string) q.Element("text"),
            Options = (from op in q.Elements("option")
                select new Option
                {
                    Id = (int) op.Element("id"),
                    Response = (string) op.Element("response")
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome man....This is neat and great...So much for XMLReader Thanks..Will not forget the power of LINQ